# Объясните мне пожалуйста, в чём смысл docker`а

Tags: php, docker, веб-сервер, lemp

Я знаю, для чего он нужен, какие есть плюсы. Но блин, неужели оно того стоит? Допустим я хочу развернуть на сервере LEMP стёк. Нафига он мне вообще нужен? Я спокойно сам могу за 10 минут всё настроить. Конфиги Nginx и PHP-FPM я сохраняю отдельно и в случае, если нужно переезжать на новый сервер, так же всё быстро настрою. Везде пишут о быстром развёртывании образа на другом сервере. И что? За всю жизнь пару тройку раз переехать на новый сервер и из-за этого использовать его? Писали про изоляцию образа, например если сервером пользуются несколько человек, что бы можно было изолировать установленное ПО друг от друга. Окей. А если я сервером управляю один? Ну установлен у меня Nginx, PHP и MySQL. Зачем мне это пихать дополнительно в Докер?

Comment: «Я спокойно сам могу за 10 минут всё настроить» — а в случае готового Docker-контейнера вы потратите примерно 0 минут

Comment: «За всю жизнь пару тройку раз переехать на новый сервер» — вы пропустили облачные технологии, когда серверы создаются и удаляются десятками в день пропорционально текущей нагрузке на проект

Comment: Ну вот ты сам себе и ответил на вопрос. Тебе - незачем. Если сервер один и управляешь им ты тоже один, то докер тебе не нужен. И не надо так горячиться